# CSS align three divs horizontally

Tags: css

I'm having an issue aligning three divs inside a parent div, the effect I need is the following

```
|IMAGE| +TEXT+ |IMAGE|
```

Each div contains an Image (2) and the text (1) respectively. Aligning them is easy, the problem is that I want the CENTER div to auto width to the size of the browsers' window and keep the other IMAGE divs always on the right and left side respectively.

Something like this for example, if the user maximizes the window:

```
|IMAGE| +++++++++++++++++++TEXT++++++++++++++++++++++++ |IMAGE|
```

As you can see, the idea is that the center div grows, and auto width but keeping the structure.

How could I get that behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
#container { text-align: center; }
#div-1 { float: left; }
#div-2 { display: inline; }
#div-3 { float: right; }
```

If that still doesn't behave how you want, please give more detailed requirements.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. I had missed the div-2 display inline part. Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI, you might want to use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;` if your DIVs are empty of content and you are just using them to hold background images. I realise this isn't the case for the question being asked, but it's something that throws a lot of people.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another inline implementation for three images side by side:

```
<div style="text-align:center">

    <div style="float: left"><img src="image1.png"/></div>

    <div style="display: inline"><img src="image2.png"/></div>

    <div style="float: right"><img src="image3.png"/></div>

</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be the exact same implementation just with the styles inline instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works rather well as well.

```
.container{width: 100%; padding: 5px;}
.fig-left {float: left;}
.text     {float: left;}
.fig-right{float: right;}

/* add margins maybe */
.text, .fig-right, p{margin: .75em;}
```

and HTML https://codepen.io/tradesouthwest/pen/MWELwGN to test

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fig-left">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1055/200/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP don't forget the alt in images QRSTUVWXYZ</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="fig-right">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1055/200/300"/>
  </div>
</div>
```